# Trying to create a google script to generate a floating button for New Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

I'm trying to create a floating button to a charity website, encouraging people to 'donate'. The idea is the button remains visible at all times, on all pages, when you scroll down. I've created a button that works using the w3schools tool, but cannot get it work on New Google Sites (which is what the site is built in). If I embed it, it puts the button in an iFrame, not on the main site.
I was hoping that creating a google Script would allow me to add it, but don't know where to start in converting the current code to a google script. Any advice very gratefully received!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #660000;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #660066;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Donate">Donate</button>


<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">Wibble.</div>



<script>
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
mybutton.style.display = "block";

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
//window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

//function scrollFunction() {
//  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
//    mybutton.style.display = "block";
//  } else {
//    mybutton.style.display = "block";
//  }
//}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  window.open("https:  TARGET DONATION SITE");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Cooper Do your site has multiple pages and the button stays active when you navigate from one page to another? Is it able to float over all the website pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it's possible to embed a Google Apps Script web app into a new Google Sites web page but that's all that can be done.

In other words, what you are trying to do, can't be done on new Google Sites.